# Save nested objects with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data REST, Hibernate, Spring JPA.
I've a model like this:

```
 @TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
@EntityListeners({ AuditingEntityListener.class })
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public abstract class AbstractEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* "UUID" and "UID" are Oracle reserved keywords -> "sid" */
    @Column(name = "sid", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    private String sid;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    // Trick to start version counting from 1 instead of 0
    @Version
    private long version = 1;

    public AbstractEntity() {
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void initializeUUID() {
        if (sid == null) {
            sid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    protected void setId(Long id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    public String getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public Instant getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public Instant getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AbstractEntity other = (AbstractEntity) obj;
        if (sid == null) {
            if (other.sid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sid.equals(other.sid)) {
            if (getId() == null) {
                if (other.getId() != null)
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!getId().equals(other.getId()))
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((sid == null) ? 0 : sid.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}



 @Entity
public class ParentEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parentEntity")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<NestedEntity> rows = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
public class NestedEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private ParentEntity parentEntity;  
}
```

I'm trying to use the default POST method provided from SDR for my ParentEntity class.
My repository is:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface ParentEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ParentEntity, Long> {
}
```

I want to make a POST from the client (Angular, but I tried first using Swagger) sending both the ParentEntity and the nested object NestedEntity because I want the save happens in the same transaction.

So I send this Json:

```
    {   
  "name": "Test",  
  "_embedded": {
    "rows": [
      {
        "name": "Nested object"        
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately just the parent entity is saved on the database. I tried - just for test - to override the method save() in `ParentEntityRepository` in order to debug and see what is received. I see the `rows` list is empty.
What's wrong with my code? Do you have some advice to understand where's my data are lost?

Comment: There is a good example of persisting nested objects here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642129/7992769

Comment: @Kirsteen I'm already using cascade =CascadeType.ALL I forgot also to say my test case server side works fine. So it's not just a problem of JPA but rather - I guess - of Spring Data REST

Comment: Why do you use `_embedded` in your payload?..

Comment: @Cepr0 Seems to be the notation to use to say that you are sending a complete nested object. If I just pass "rows" the servers expect it is a URI and raise and exception.

Comment: Second question: do you have exported NestedEntityRepo?

Comment: @Cepr0 Sorry I didn't write that, but yes I exported NestedEntityRepository as well

Comment: In this case you can only create nested objects with NestedRepo when use links to it to add them to the parent object. Or you can turn off export of NestedRepo and then create nested objects with parent object in one payload...

Comment: @Cepr0 I just tried to remove NestedEntityRepo but unfortunately the nested object is not yet persisted.

Comment: From my example: [this](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/src/main/java/restvotes/domain/entity/Menu.java) is 'parent object' and [this](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/src/main/java/restvotes/domain/entity/MenuItem.java) is a 'nested object'. Exported is off in the 'nested' repo. And this is their behavior: https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/readme_en.md#apimenus (see POST/PUT command) - all worked as expected...

Comment: May be this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276043 will be helpful...

Comment: @Cepr0 I tried your project and it works like you said. I'll try to figure out why mine is not working understanding your. Thanks

Comment: I can assume that it's happening due to a bidirectional association between your entities. Try to remove reference to `ParentEntity` from the child entity.

Comment: @Cepr0 Yep, I arrived to the same conclusion. Is there a way, in your opinion, to mantain a bidirectional association in this case?

Comment: Yes )) I think it's enough to implement a `setChildren` method like this: `public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
  if (this.children != null) {
   this.children.forEach(child -> child.setParent(null));
  }
  if (children != null) {
   children.forEach(child -> child.setParent(this));
  }
  this.children = children;
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn off exporting of the `NestedEntityRepository` (or remove it):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface NestedEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<NestedEntity, UUID> {
}
```

And provide synchronization of your bidirectional associations between two entities. For example like this:

```
public class ParentEntity {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parentEntity")
    private List<NestedEntity> rows;

    public void setRows(List<NestedEntity> rows) {
        if (this.rows != null) {
            this.rows.forEach(row -> row.setParentEntity(null));
        }
        if (rows != null) {
            rows.forEach(row -> row.setParentEntity(this));
        }
        this.rows = rows;
    }  
}
```

Or just turn you association to unidirectional.